# SQL Server 'UNION' (Distinct)

Tags: sql-server, union

I've been pondering this for a while and looking around, but have found no clear answer as to why SQL Server (it's the only version of SQL we use, unfortunately) utilises a `DISTINCT` form of `UNION`. Is there some underlying reason why this is so, as opposed to being `UNION ALL` by default?

Comment: Based on the SQL standard AFAIK. Sets don't contain duplicates.

Comment: This is what the SQL standard requires (this is actually one of the few things where all DBMS behave the same way)

Comment: Then you'd have "UNION" vs "UNION DISTINCT" and some people could ask the same question...

Comment: I see. To be honest, I would want to know that there's a problem with my data in the first place (by the return of duplicates).  But, nice to know - thanks for your input everyone.